# Haar system and martingale

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Today our lecturer used martingale theory to show that the Haar system is a basis for $L_1[0,1]$ (we're operating on the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B},P)$, where $P$ is the Lebesgue measure). There are two of the steps which i can't entirely get my head around:

He took a sequence $(t_n)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and defined $X_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, by $X_n=\sum_{m=1}^{n}t_mh_m$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $h_n$ is the haar function. He then argued that this is a martingale. I have no trouble seeing that this is measurable and integrable. However he made the following argument:

Let $(B_j)$, $j=1,...,N$, be a maximal set of atoms in $\mathcal{F}_k$ for a fixed $k$. This set is finite. Then

$E(X_n|\mathcal{F}_k)=\sum_{j=1}^NP(B_j)^{-1}\int_{B_j}X_ndP\cdot 1_{B_j}=\sum_{j=1}^NP(B_j)^{-1}\int_{B_j}\sum_{m=1}^nt_mh_mdP\cdot 1_{B_j}$
$\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{j=1}^{N}P(B_j)^{-1}P(B_j)X_{n-1}\cdot 1_{B_j}=X_{n-1}$.

Note that the first step is a direct consequence of a formula we proved earlier on the day. I have marked the step that i do not understand. Can anyone explain why I can do this?

The second thing I do not understand came in the proof of the following result:

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we put $A_n=\{ t\in [0,1] | h_n(t)=1\}\cup\{ t\in[0,1] | h_n(t)=-1\}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $f\in L_1[0,1]$. Show that if either $B=\{ t\in[0,1] | h_{n+1}(t)=1\}$ or $B=\{ t\in[0,1] | h_{n+1}(t)=-1\}$, then

$\int_BE(f|\mathcal{F}_n)(t)dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{A_{n+1}}f(t)dt$.

Proof: Let $B_1=\{ t\in[0,1] | h_{n+1}(t)=1\}$ and $B_{-1}=\{ t\in[0,1] | h_{n+1}(t)=-1\}$. Then $A_{n+1}=B_1\cup B_{-1}$, where the union is disjoint. Then

$\int_{A_{n+1}}f(t)dt=\int_{B_1}f(t)dt+\int_{B_{-1}}f(t)dt$.

Since a $\mathcal{F}_{n}$-measurable random variable is constant on an atom in $\mathcal{F}_n$, we get

$\int_{B_1}E(f|\mathcal{F}_n)(t)dt=\int_{B_{-1}}E(f|\mathcal{F}_n)(t)dt$.

Then we get the result. But why? How do we combine the result with the expected values with the result without?